# starting with graphql-problems with queries

Tags: graphql

Hi I have just started with graphql so bear with me and be very explicit.
I have a database in MySQL with a list of departments with the attributes of id, name and array of users. I have explicited that in the schema in this way

```
type Department {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  user: [User]
}
```

then I have created a couple of queries, ie. allDepartments and getDepartment in this way

```
type Query {
  departments: [Department!]!
  getDept(id: ID!): Department!
}
```

the resolver functions are those ones

```
Query: {
    departments: async (parent, args, context) => {
      return context.prisma.department.findMany();
    },
    getDept: async (parent, args, context) => {
      return context.prisma.department.findUnique({
        where: { id: args.id },
      });
    },
  },
```

however
when I query the alldepartments, I get the list but the user array is empty (whereas there is at least one person each)
with getDept I manage to get the department only if I hardcode the id in the where obj. how can I implement a query where I can pass the id as argument and have the findunique to catch that particular one? can I use the name of the department instead of the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the args.id needs to be parsed as int
findUnique is not the right method since it has to be used with fields that are marked as "unique" in the schema